Is there a word that means the opposite of 'embarrassing'?
I have scoured every thesaurus I can find but cannot seem to find a (single) word that I can use to replace 'embarrasing' to signify the opposite of embarrassing (as opposed to the lack of embarrassment).
i.e. "he's embarrassing" becomes "he's (the opposite of embarrassing)" as in "he is something (that makes me feel proud)".
For comparison, the opposite of 'it's cold!' would be 'it's hot!'.
"It's not cold" (or "he's not embarrassing") describes a lack of coldness that could mean it's hot, but doesn't really imply it's hot, per se.. as a stand alone statement, it suggests the temperate midpoint between hot and cold.

Of course, there will be some reason why unembarrassing won't do. Won't there?

Haha, there is, of course, a reason - 'unembarrassing' isn't the opposite of embarrassing - it suggests neutrality. The idea is for the word to evoke that feeling of pride at the opposite end of the embarrassing spectrum.

What does "he's embarassing" mean? A person can be embarassed, and a situation that causes someone to be embarassed can be embarassing (e.g. a wardrobe malfunction). But what does it mean for a person to be embarassing? It's hard to come up with an opposite when the word itself doesn't really make sense.

@Barmar Someone or something that is embarrassing causes embarrassment. "He's embarrassing" would likely be used in a context where he is causing the speaker or himself embarrassment, or has a proclivity to do so. If your coworker gets drunk at a work event and tells off-color jokes, you might say his conduct, or he himself, is embarrassing - he might be embarrassing himself, or be embarrassing his boss, or simply be embarrassing in general. I see no issue at all with saying a person is embarrassing.

@NuclearHoagie I think we would say "He's an embarassment" or "He's embarassing himself".

@Barmar Those are certainly other ways of saying it, but I see nothing special or different about referring to a person as embarrassing, as opposed to any other noun like a thing or situation. I see little difference between "my coworker's behavior is embarrassing", "the things my coworker does are embarrassing", and "my coworker is embarrassing".

Embarrassment is a condition which disturbs the normal state of composure. So one is comparing a condition to a state which will not, necessarily, result in two single-word expressions.

Pride has the sense of "something that makes you feel proud" already. "He is my pride" is an expression used also; which can serve as an opposite of "He is embarrassing".

I don't really understand the obsessive (in these parts) search for single words to express complex concepts and I don't think there is anything wrong with what OP has already (nearly) written.  Perhaps

It fills me with pride to show him off at family get togethers.

as the opposite of

It embarrasses me dreadfully to have him accompany me to family get togethers.


+1 for the thing about single word request and opposites.

‘Embarrassing’ is a concept that allows negation, but in my opinion (and the entries in the Thesaurus used by the OP) does not have an opposite, and indeed the OP has not described any emotional state which she considers to be its opposite.
NB. The question is not “is there a state that one might consider the opposite to ‘embarrassing’” (which would in any case not be a question about the language).
Coda
This answer may be regarded by some as unsatisfactory because it is unsubstantiated. Admittedly it is impossible to prove something does not exist. However there are so many questions of this sort that I think it worth making the point that although ‘cold’ has an opposite, ‘turquoise’ does not. Likewise “embarrassing”.

Since embarrassing (adj.) means

Causing a feeling of self-conscious confusion and distress
M-W

reassuring (adj.), which means

restoring or intended to restore confidence : reducing or eliminating
worry or uncertainty
M-W

may come close to expressing the opposite. For example, if you are self-conscious about a new article of clothing you are wearing to the point of beginning to feel some embarrassment, that embarrassment might vanish after being reassured by receiving one or two compliments on it.


"I really feel bad," I admit, "That was so embarrassing."
Dylan shakes
his head and leans closer, reassuring me.
"It was an accident and
it didn't even hit me," he says, "There's no reason for guilt."
Christine Soltis; Thirty (2011)


Harré (1990) argues that embarrassment functions as a largely
non-verbal, social signal that is sent by the transgressor and
received automatically by a recipient audience. Behaviours, such as
blushing, eye gaze directed at the floor and fidgeting, indicate to
the audience that the transgressor is aware of his or her 'error',
which allows the audience the option of ignoring the error or
providing reassurance that all is well.
Graham Russell;
Essential Psychology for Nurses and Other Health Professionals (2002)


In the same vein, you may say "Dylan shakes his head and leans closer, comforting me". If you comfort someone, you make them feel less worried, unhappy, or upset, for example by saying kind things to them..

@Graffito You can add it as an answer.

He is embarrassing because he makes me feel some or even all of the following

uncomfortable, awkward, self-conscious, ashamed, mortified, humiliated, crushed

If, on the other hand, he makes me feel comfortable, relaxed, confident, and proud then he is

heartening, bolstering, buoying, inspiring, encouraging, cheering, and confidence boosting

Depending on the precise context, perhaps the single word that most answers the OP is hearten -

to make more cheerful or confident

